# Laravel is Validating but not Displaying Error Message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following validations...

```
<?php

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'refrence_number' => 'integer',
        'region' => 'integer',
        'tregion' => 'integer',
        'tdistrict' => 'integer',
        'district' => 'integer',
        'zone' => 'integer',
        'tzone' => 'integer',
        'ward_no' => 'integer',
        'tward_no' => 'integer',
    ]);
}
```

The validation is working well, but it doesn't give a message such as:

> This field should be an integer.

The registration page only reloads. Should I have to manually assign the message as well?

Comment: validation errors aren't rendered automatically, if you show us the view code for the registration page we could help

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign the message manually but you should have this sort of code in view to show the error message:

```
   @if ($errors->has('name'))
          <span class="help-block">
                 <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
          </span>
   @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

An old question but can help someone new. 
Should try something like this:

```
$rules = array(
    "title" => "required",
    "description" => "required",
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if($validator->fails()){
    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator->messages());
}
else{ 
    // do your thing. 
}
```

Display errors like:

```
@if($errors->any())
    @foreach($errors->all() as $e1)
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        {{$e1}}
    </div>
    @endforeach
@endif
```